# Deciphering Sell By codes

Tags: food-safety

How to decipher code on Kroger spice bottle "15:58 Sell by Aug 24 15PS2"?  Please explain, as I have many others.

Comment: FYI, they are called BBD's, or "Best By Date Codes" in the domestic US and NA.  You can actually call Kroger's QA and ask them to decode the date for you; this would be the best approach as it'd be most accurate.